# how to add a submenu in UberMenu for wordpress directly into the database (out of memory error)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, submenu

I am using UberMenu in my wordpress based website. When I try to access the menus from wp-admin. it gives me out of memory error. My host is not powerful enough to manage UberMenu

All I want to do is add one sub menu to main menu item.

Considering my menu in wp-admin are not working, I was thinking if i can directly insert the required data/records in the wp database.

Any sugguestion where the data for the menus is saved.

any help  will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivate UberMenu 2 plugin

Add the Menu/Submenu

Avtivate UberMenu 2 plugin

Problems solved.